# Is it possible to show coloured html rich text Notification on Android?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-push-notification

I want to show a custom notification designed by the user as the notification. For example, I have the following notification:

```
<h2>
    <span style="background-color: rgb(255, 156, 0);">Testing</span> 
    <u style="">HTML</u>&nbsp;
    <span style="font-weight: 400;">tags </span>
    <span style="background-color: rgb(231, 99, 99);">highlight</span> 
    <span style="font-weight: 400;"> test.</span>
</h2>
```

I use  `Spanned htmlText = Html.fromHtml(msg);` to parse the message.
When notification is shown I do see the bold text and the underline text,
but I don't see anything highlighted. Is there anyway to achieve it and show the colours, or Android simply doesn't support it?

Comment: Well! Its good to say its work on condition when `App` in `Foreground` but it will not work when app in `background`!

Comment: When the app is in foreground I still don't see the colour. When it's in the background I see the message with all the html tags - but this is server side issue and I will deal with it later. Currently I want to display the highlighted text and it doesn't work.

Comment: You might want to switch custom remote views